# Rails converting Javascript array to Hash?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I JS I send this to rails:

`[{name: "Jon"}, {name: "Jane"}]`

I expect Rails/Ruby to interpret it into the same structure, but instead it converts it to a hash like this:

`{ "0" => {"name" => "Jon"}, "1" => {"name" => "Jane"} }`

Any idea why this happens, or how to prevent it?

Comment: In this particular case call `values` method on hash.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually sending `[{name: "Jon"}, {name: "Jane"}]`, you're sending `"[{name: "Jon"}, {name: "Jane"}]"` so rails has to convert it to something or else you'd be doing some messy regex's to get at the data you want.  So rails converts it to a [HashWithIndifferentAccess Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) for you.  I highly doubt you want to hack at rails internals, so why not just parse your code the way rails presents it instead of coercing it into another format?

Answer (score 0):

That's a correct behaviour. If you're interested in sending Array as parameters, you have to use  `some_field_name[]` type of field instead of simple "field_name" in javascript.